# Why is the C# CreateObject so much more verbose than VB.NET?

Tags: c#, vb.net, com

I am looking to convert some VB6/COM+ code to C#/COM+

However where in VB6 or VB.NET I have:

```
Dim objAdmin
objAdmin = Server.CreateObject("AppAdmin.GUI")
objAdmin.ShowPortal()
```

In C# it seems like I have to do the following:

```
object objAdmin = null;
System.Type objAdminType = System.Type.GetTypeFromProgID("AppAdmin.GUI");
m_objAdmin = System.Activator.CreateInstance(objAdminType);
objAdminType.InvokeMember("ShowPortal", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, objAdmin, null);
```

Is there a way of getting c# to not have to use the InvokeMember function and just call the function directly?

Comment: Short answer: Because VB was designed from the start for consuming COM objects, while C# wasn't.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Is there a way of getting c# to not have to use the InvokeMember function and just call the function directly?

Yes, as of C# 4 with [dynamic typing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264736.aspx):

```
dynamic admin = Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetTypeFromProgID("AppAdmin.GUI"));
admin.ShowPortal();
```

It's still more verbose in the `CreateObject` part, but you could always wrap that up in a method call if you wanted. (There *may* be an existing call I'm not aware of, or you could try to find whatever VB is calling in that case - I don't know the details of `Server.CreateObject`.)

Note that dynamic typing is richer than *just* making reflection simpler, but it certainly does that. Behind the scenes, the same kind of thing will be happening in both cases though - it's still not going to be as fast as static binding, but it's almost certainly fast *enough*.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, you can use the [`dynamic`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264741.aspx) keyword

```
dynamic objAdmin = System.Activator.CreateInstance(objAdminType);
objAdmin.ShowPortal();
```

Answer (score -1):

If you have access to the actual class type, you can do it as follows:

```
AppAdminClass m_objAdmin = (AppAdminClass)System.Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(AppAdminClass));
m_objAdmin.ShowPortal();
```