# Reflection does not reflect method in interface in C#

Tags: c#-4.0, dynamic, system.reflection

I cannot figure out what the deal is with this code. "command" = `Park`, and the Park method exists in the interface. "method", however, just equals null, so it throws an exception when I hit invoke. The debugger kicks in, and so I was able to make sure that everything looks OK. Why does method not get set?

The scope object is defined. It is a com object.  I expanded the dynamic view of the scope object and all it shows is properties or something (blue 3d boxes, not hand and paper), no methods. Is that the problem? But why, since I am referring to ITelescope and don't do anything with scope until I try to invoke the method, which was not set.

I got the Activator code from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12319422/258482).

```
ITelescope scope = (ITelescope)Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetTypeFromProgID(scopeProgID));
var method = typeof(ITelescope).GetMethod(command);
method.Invoke( scope, new object[0]{ } );
```

Comment: If the method named `"Park"` is defined in the `ITelescope` interface, your code should find it. Note that the names are case-sensitive, and make sure there are no leading or trailing spaces around the name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I remembered that I had asked [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12407213/258482) about interfaces and reflection. The problem has something to do with interop types. To fix it you right click on the offending reference in the reference list of the project, click properties, and set "embed interop types" to false.